# Unable to connect / clone GitLab repo in eclipse, even though able to connect to it from command line

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, gitlab, egit

I was trying to clone repository in eclipse from gitlab.
It was showing that I cannot checkout/commit repository unless generate ssh key pairs. It further gave me [this](http://10.30.5.71/help/ssh/README) link. I followed steps [there](http://10.30.5.71/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair). It created following files:

```
C:\Users\User Name\.ssh\id_rsa
C:\Users\User Name\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

Then I copy pasted public key back to GitLab.

Then ran this:

```
C:\Users\User Name>ssh -T git@xx.xx.xx.xx
The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:mZNjLhcagbXDWoshrvVT7wsMNbQ97UTGlJSfUsH6231.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\User Name/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\User Name/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to GitLab, User Name!
```

So I feel I able to connect from command link.

However I am not able to connect in Eclipse.
I specified id_rsa file in eclipse as stated [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration).

Then I tried to clone repo in eclipse as follows:

[image]

But it keeps asking me password, without ever connecting:

[image]
My information in gitlab profile:

- Email: user.name@domain.com
- Name: User Name
- User name: UserN

Whats wrong going on here? What I am missing / doing wrong?

PS: I have masked some text of repo URI and my username in 2nd image.

Comment: Just guessed: Try to check the 'Store in Secure Store'-Checkbox, maybe this helps.

Comment: Nope I tried that several times. Can you have a look at my own answer? Something worked for me, but dont know why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In first screen shot, when I put `git` instead of `UserN` for User, it worked. Afterwards it asked me password for `id_rsa`, which when provided, started cloning repository. Dont know why this worked. Can someone shed some light?